# React Native + Android: borderRadius alternative?

Tags: react-native

I need to make my `View` circular on a non solid colored background.

I tried using `borderRadius` and `overflow: 'hidden'`, but it isn't working. I see that this is a known issue with React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198

There seems to be workarounds for images that are on top of a solid background, but my background is dynamic and on top of an image so therefore I can't hardcode it.

Are there any alternatives to get something like this to work?

The black square should be a circle:

[image]

Here's the code (P.S. I'm using react native webrtc, that's where I'm getting RTCView, but I think this works with a plain old `View`):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  remoteVideoContainer: {
    borderRadius: 50,
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: 100,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  video: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default VideoView = ({
  videoURL,
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.remoteVideoContainer}>
      <RTCView
        style={styles.video}
        streamURL={videoURL}
        mirror={true}
        objectFit="cover"
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure if you can style the RTCView. The code doesn't expose a styling prop. https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/RTCView.js

Comment: yeh i looked, which is why i tried the solution above which is to wrap it in a view, but borderRadius doesn't work on android